# Why does WordPress keep showing me error messages?

Tags: debug, wp-debug, errors

I'm trying to hide error messages on a WordPress installation on a shared hosting. I added the following code to my config.

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

This is pretty much what I find in any article regarding this topic. However, it doesn't work. I keep getting error messages. What could be the reason it isn't working for me?

---

**A little update.** One error I sometimes get is a "notice". When I keep all these three lines and put error_reporting to "0" as suggested in the answers, I still get the notice error.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', 0 );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

However, when I comment the last 3 lines, the notice disappears:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
//ini_set('display_errors','Off');
//ini_set('error_reporting', 0 );
//define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Does that make any sense to anyone? What's happening here?

Comment: What error messages are you getting, and where?

Comment: I'm getting this error message on a search result page: "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /www/htdocs/....php on line 55" for example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this line

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
```

will override other error settings. Will display all errors, even 'benign' ones, to the screen and error log file.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I read on multiple sites that you need to place this line in order to turn off error reporting, one of them being wpbeginner: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-turn-off-php-errors-in-wordpress/

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php .

Comment: No matter what I set there, it doesn't change anything. I still get the error messages.

Comment: It depends on where you put the command. Is it in a template? Or your functions file? Or your child theme (because we don't want to edit the parent theme)? It may be that a command in the theme is overriding that command. I'd make a child theme (if not using one already), then modify the template that you are debugging to include the above command.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0 );
```

instead of:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
```

because **E_ALL** tell to show every error.

Comment: Well, on every website I find on the web that deals with the topic of hiding error messages in WordPress, they tell me to do it exactly as I posted it, with ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ), so I'm guessing it's correct like that. Anyway, no matter what I put there, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting php.ini is properly configured, is not necessary to use `ini_set()` in your wp-config.php when you are defining `WP_DEBUG`.

What is `WP_DEBUG`? It's a constant used in WP to determine what error notice settings to apply.  When WP loads, one of the functions that is run on every load is `wp_debug_mode()`.  I highly suggest you [review what it does](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_mode/) so you know why you originarily do not need to use `ini_set()` - because it's already being done in `wp_debug_mode()`.  So what you're doing by adding this to your wp-config.php is the equivalent of flipping the switch on/off/on/off over and over.

When `WP_DEBUG` is set to true, it sets `error_reporting( E_ALL )`.  Otherwise, `error_reporting()` is set to a lesser value.  You should not manually set this to 0 unless you know what you're doing - otherwise, you're shutting off all error reporting, which will make it hard when you actually need to debug something but forgot that you turned off all notices.  Unless you really have a need to do so, just let WP handle setting the `error_reporting()` value.

Next, when `WP_DEBUG` is true, it handles the display of errors based on the `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` value.  If it's true, then `ini_set()` is run to set 'display_errors' to "1", which will display errors on the screen.  If `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` is set to false, it will set 'display_errors' to "0" which will suppress display of any errors.

I hope this didn't confuse the issue, and I hope that you can see why the last set you had (where all but `WP_DEBUG` was commented out) suppressed the messages.

If you want error messages turned off, just set `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to false, and get rid of the `ini_set()` lines you have.

Comment: I did what you said in your last sentence, but it doesn't work. I still get warnings.